# How to convert a java double value to Date/Time format (HH:mm:ss) in Java?

Tags: java

I receive input in double (Eg: 12803.000000) which represents time in hours:minutes:seconds, ignore the values after the dot. All I want is to convert this double value to something like 1:28:03 as in HH:mm:ss format using java code. How to achieve the expected outcome?

Code I tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String time = df.format(new Date((long) ((Double.parseDouble("12803.000000"))*60*60*1000)));
System.out.println("time>>"+time);
```

This code is giving me the ouput as 16:30 which is not the expected result.

TIA!!

Comment: Convert double to String then use DateFormat.

Comment: That is a seriously broken representation you are starting from.

Comment: @mannedear - You misunderstand me.  What I am saying that using the floating point number `12803.000000` to represent `1:28:03` is nonsense from a mathematical perspective.  Your difficulties are *caused* by that nonsense.  A better solution - use a more meaningful representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double x = 12803.000000;
String s = String.format("%06d", (int)x);   
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
Date date = format.parse(s);
```

I don't know how your double value is representing a date, but the code can solve your example question.

Comment: +1 for providing a simple solution. Further I have made small adjustment on top of your code to just extract the time alone and I have shared it in the solution. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

This below code should give you the desired result.

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws ParseException {
        Double value = 12803.000000;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
        String intValueStr = String.valueOf(value.intValue() );
        int length = intValueStr.length();
        int missingDigits = 6- length;
        String strForTimeParsing = intValueStr;
        for(int i =0; i< missingDigits;i++){
            strForTimeParsing = "0"+strForTimeParsing;
        }
        System.out.println("Final String after padding Zeros at the start = "+strForTimeParsing);

        Date parsedDate = format.parse(strForTimeParsing);
        String format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(parsedDate);

        System.out.println("Resulted Formatted Time = "+format1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. Thanks zhh for your helping hand.

```
                    double x = 12803.000000;
                    String s = String.format("%06d", (int)x);
                    System.out.println("String val>>"+s);
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
                    DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    try {
                        Date date = format.parse(s);
                        System.out.println("date>>"+date);
                        System.out.println("time in String format>>"+format1.format(date));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Output: time in String format>>01:28:03